# How to determine the size of an PE executable file from headers and or footers

Tags: windows, portable-executable

Assuming you have a stream of data or a block of bytes you want to carve, how can you determine the size of the executables?

There are numerous headers inside the PE executable format, but what header sections do I use to determine (if possible) the total length of the executable?

Here is a picture of the file format.

[image: PE File Format]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the PE file is well formed, the calculation can be simplified as (pseudo-code):

```
size = IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders

foreach section_header in section_headers:
    size += section_header.SizeOfRawData
```

Where:

- `SizeOfHeaders` is a member of [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.
- ([`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) structure is part of [`IMAGE_NT_HEADERS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680336(v=vs.85).aspx))

`SizeOfHeaders` field gives the length of all the headers (note: including the 16-bit stub).

- Each section header is an [`IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680341(v=vs.85).aspx) structure
- `SizeOfRawData` field gives the length of each section on disk.

---

**Example with notepad** (Windows 10):

- `SizeOfHeaders` : 0x400

[image]

- `SizeOfRawData`of each sections :

  - .text: 0x15400
  - .data: 0x800
  - .idata: 0x1A00
  - .rsrc: 0x19C00
  - .reloc: 0x1600

(note: `SizeOfRawData` is called `Raw Size` in the below picture):

[image]

Sum everything:

```
>>> size_of_headers = 0x400
>>> sec_sizes = [0x15400, 0x800, 0x1a00, 0x19c00, 0x1600]
>>> size_of_headers + sum(sec_sizes)
207872
>>>
```

**Total size**: 207872 bytes.

Verification:

[image]

Note: the above calculation doesn't take into account if the PE is badly formed or if there is an overlay.

Comment: Or if the PE file has information outside of any section. This is common for installers.

Comment: In your section with SizeOfImage, SizeOfHeaders, and Checksum, what does the second column refer to?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Offsets (in hex) of the fields in the PE file. The screenshot shows only a small part of a tool called [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php).

Comment: If the PE file has information outside of any section (like an installer) and is digitally signed, you can calculate the total size by summing `VirtualAddress` and `Size` of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER::DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY]`. This works because the signature is always appended to the end the PE file, after any payload. [See this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47650900/7571258).

Comment: It seems the same as `SizeOfCode + SizeOfInitializedData`?