# Get length of executable file

Tags: file, executable

**Situation**

I have a `carved file` with an executable file at the beginning `(MZ)`.
The problem is that I don't know where this executable file ends and the new file begins.

**Question**

How can I find out the length or end of this executable file when this information isn't in the header?

Comment: What if you can't?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the size of an PE executable file from headers and or footers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684660/how-to-determine-the-size-of-an-pe-executable-file-from-headers-and-or-footers)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could calculate the size of the executable if you have enough data of its header. Assuming it is a PE header, all the informations you need are on [this SO past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684660/how-to-determine-the-size-of-an-pe-executable-file-from-headers-and-or-footers)