# Where is the digital signature stored when code signing a exe file in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, code-signing, portable-executable

As stated in the question title. However, I am using a "trick" where i store extra data after the executable to be used at runtime (see [here](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27979)).

Signing my executable appears to break this 'trick' however, so my question is where is the signature stored in the exe (PE) file?

I am using[`signtool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx) from microsoft to sign my executable.

Comment: "*I am using a "trick" where i store extra data after the executable to be used at runtime*" - dont do that. Setup an actual resource for custom data. It is the official and preferred way to store data in an executable, there are APIs for accessing and updating resources, and they won't break when code signing is applied

Comment: @RemyLebeau it's not my code unfortunately, i can't change the way it works without a dramatic rewrite that would take months.

Comment: changing how custom data is stored in the EXE should not take months to rewrite. Hours at most. And you should do it if you want to avoid breaking code signing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I misspoke, it's not that it's difficult to write, it's that the library is in use by thousands of people and i cannot change it without introducing a backwards incompatible change. Please, think of my question as academic then -- how does code signing change an executable? I can then convince myself if what you say is correct -- that the current approach cannot work with code signing :)

Comment: see my answer for official documentation on the PE format when signed

Comment: @RemyLebeau The "trick" is a commonly used technique to append data to executables and saying "don't do that" is a bit too simple of an answer. There are good reasons for doing so, for instance if the data is very large, it won't fit in the resource section. Also this technique doesn't necessarily break when code signing is is applied.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An embedded digital signature is always appended to the end of the executable file, whether or not you have custom data attached to it. The attached data is included in the hash of the signature.

The location and size of the signature is stored in the security directory of the PE header. Extracting that information goes like this:

- Locate and read the [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header32) of the PE file.
- `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER::DataDirectory` is an array of [`IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_data_directory) structures. Index it by `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY`. You may also use dbghlp API [`ImageDirectoryEntryToDataEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-imagedirectoryentrytodataex).
- `IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY::VirtualAddress` contains the *file offset* (not the RVA) of the signature and `IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY::Size` contains the size of the signature.

References:

- [PE Format (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format)
- [Peering inside the PE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms809762(v=msdn.10)) (somewhat more readable, with examples)
- [IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY values](https://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_in_depth_look_into_pe_format_pt1_figures.htm)
- [The Case of the Missing Digital Signatures Tab](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/01/11/the-case-of-the-missing-digital-signatures-tab/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I've got it more or less working HOWEVER, there seems to be a buffer of bytes placed between the previous end of file (before codesigning took place) and the digital signature. Sometimes it's 8 bytes, sometimes it's 9 bytes, sometimes it's 10 bytes....It's super confusing -- do you know anything about this random 'buffer' of bytes that appears before the digital signature? Unless i can predict how many bytes there will be i either have to give up, or do a kind of 'search' to find my own custom data...

Comment: @horseyguy This is propably for alignment of the signature start offset. I don't know about the exact scheme behind this. I suggest you either prepend a header to your custom data, that specifies the actual size or enclose your data in unique boundary strings (e. g. a GUID), that you could search for.

Comment: There may be padding, but also some other applications will append data after the header (for example, SFX archives will append the actual zip file after the PE information and before the signature.

Answer (score 7):

The format of a signed PE file is documented by Microsoft:

[Windows Authenticode Portable Executable Signature Format](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Authenticode_PE.docx) *[This link downloads a WORD doc]*

Comment: This document isn't relevant except for this sentence, which still leaves things unclear: "_Authenticode signatures can be “embedded” in a Windows PE file, in a location specified by the Certificate Table entry in Optional Header Data Directories._"

Comment: @zett42 it is hardly unclear as the document shows where that table is located and what it contains.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Sorry to bother you Remy. Seems like there was some  issue on my dev VM. It worked fine when I tried it on my host OS.