# Get signature of signed file in C#

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I am trying to verify if a file is digitally signed and if the signature is valid. This is the closest post to my need on SO: [How to verify digital signature in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660195/how-to-verify-digital-signature-in-c-sharp#answers)

The problem I have is how do I get the signature of the signed file in the first place?

UPDATE: Thank you for guidance.  Both .exe .js and files are signed with DigiCert Certificate Utility. I found the signature in the .js file itself. Not sure where .exe's is.

I believe the signing algorithm is determined by the certificate.
In the details tab of the Certificate details on windows, can be seen that signature algorithm is `sha256RSA`, signature hash algorithm is `sha256` and public key is RSA(2048 Bits).

Comment: The way where the signature can be found depends on the algorithm and usage of the program using the algorithm. Please [edit] your question to include the algorithm and program you are using to sign a file and check the documentation of that program.

Comment: @Progman thanks for taking your time. It's .exe file that is problematic.

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060009/checking-digital-signature-on-exe or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646135/where-is-the-digital-signature-stored-when-code-signing-a-exe-file-in-windows

Comment: What about zip?

Comment: Still depends on the program you use for signing a ZIP file. You might want to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging.packagedigitalsignaturemanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0